# Would have been beeping

Tags: conditional-constructions, present-tense, modality

I would just like to know if this is idiomatic?

If that machine were broken, that would have been beeping since I turned it on.

Answer (score 1):

*Would have been beeping* is idiomatic (though *would have beeped* would also fit).

*That* in the second clause isn't idiomatic, unless you are referring to something different from the machine, eg you're pointing to a part of it. *It* would be expected.